# How to suppress warnings of type "The Element X in namespace X has invalid child element ..." within Microsoft.CppBuild.targets

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I have a very large C# project, with over 100 warnings, all triggered by the file:

```
Microsoft.CppBuild.targets
```

Is there a way to suppress these types of warnings:

```
The element 'ResourceCompile' in namespace 
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' has invalid child element 
'MinimalRebuildFromTracking' in namespace 
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'. List of possible elements
expected: 'Culture, PreprocessorDefinitions, UndefinePreprocessorDefinitions,
AdditionalIncludeDirectories, IgnoreStandardIncludePath, ShowProgress,
NullTerminateStrings, SuppressStartupBanner, ResourceOutputFileName' in namespace
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'.  C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets 172 10
Miscellaneous Files
```

Other warnings start with:

```
The Element 'Midl' ...
The Element 'PropertyGroup' ...
The Element 'Manifest' ...
The Element 'Link' ...
The Element 'ItemGroup' ...
The Element 'ClCompile' ...
```

### Environment

- Visual Studio 2010 SP1
- ReSharper

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution was to close the file "Microsoft.CppBuild.targets".

Comment: Basically a minor bug. If opened in Visual Studio it does a validation of their XML but it does not comply do their XML-Schema.

Comment: @tmanthey Glad that this fixed the issue for you. While we're on the topic, Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 are miles ahead of Visual Studio 2010, once you upgrade you could never go back :)

Comment: Totally agree but happened to me in Visual Studio 2013. Still not fixed.

Comment: Erk. Perhaps its fixed in 2015?